# How to insert data of a single form into two collections using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how do i insert the first three data coming from req.body into event collection and rest into personal collection

```
app.post("/api/bookings", async(req, res) => {
          const {
            eventName,
            date,
            venue,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            contact,
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
          } = req.body;

          try {
            await new Event(req.body).save();
            await new Personal(req.body).save()
            console.log("inserted");
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } 
})
```

Comment: i'm importing Event schema and personal schema from another file.

Comment: You can create two difference obj  for event and personal to set values respectively and then you can  save with respective schema object

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different objects for event and personal to store data

```
app.post("/api/bookings", async(req, res) => {
          const {
            eventName,
            date,
            venue,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            contact,
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
          } = req.body;

          const EventData = {
              eventName,
              data,
              venue
          }

          const PersonalData = {
               firstname,
                lastname,
                email,
                contact,
                address1,
                address2,
                city,
                state,
                zip,
          }
       
          try {
            await new Event(EventData).save();
            await new Personal(PersonalData).save()
            console.log("inserted");
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } 
})
```